# Jupyter Kernel Dies when Attempting a Simple Plot (Python)

Tags: python, kernel, matplotlib, jupyter

My Jupyter Notebook cannot even draw a simple plot anymore.
Until yesterday, it could plot all kinds of plots of matplotlib and seaborn.
It is not a memory error because there are 1.6 GB available.
Also, I updated jupyter, matplotlib and seaborn.

[image: Dead Kernel]

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser.  Is also Python updated [a died kernel error suggests me to check it]?   Did you reboot the machine? What does it happens if you try something on the browser version? You can answer this little questions [edit]ing your post. In case you solved by yourself you can add the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem--fixed it with `conda install nomkl`.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Anaconda, that's how the issue was solved but that was like surgery after 3 years of using jupyter.